# How to take off the part of any array between those numbers?

Tags: java

My question is, given two numbers, how to take off the sector of the array between those numbers
in any array.

For example, given these arrays:
{3,2,5,4,8,7,9}, {1,3,2,7,8,4}
which method will take off all the numbers between 2 and 8 in both arrays?

Many thanks.

Comment: Define 'take off'. Remove? If so, you're out of luck, because Arrays (int[]) are static in size. Or are you talking about a container of some sort? Please be more specific.

Comment: And by *all the numbers between 2 and 8 in both arrays*, do you mean all the common numbers, i.e. those that are in both arrays, and that are between 2 and 8?

Comment: smells like homework to me

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
int[] array1 = {3,2,5,4,8,7,9};
int[] array2 = {1,3,2,7,8,4};
ArrayList newArray1 = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++)
{
    if (array1[i] > 2 && array1[i] < 8)
    {
        newArray1.add(array1[i]);
    }
}
```

You can do the same for the other array. Additionaly, you can add the numbers back in to an array of integers, since you now know the size of the integer array.

```
int[] array1new = new int[newArray1.size()];
for (int j = 0; j < newArray1.size(); j++)
{
    array1new[j] = newArray1.get(j);
}
```

Comment: +1 I would use `array1` instead of `Array1` and `if (2 < array1[i] && array1[i] < 8)`

Comment: Agreed! Allow me to edit that!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in method in the Java APIs. You will have to write one or find a third-party library that extracts a sub-array from the original one.

You find the index of the first value then the index of the second value and then you can use `Arrays.copyOfRange(array, from to);`